# Wordpress theme from scratch shortcode error

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I am transfering my static website into Wordpress. I have created necessary files (header.php, index.php, etc.) and separated content to these files.

Site is working perfectly now, but when I try to include any gallery plugin via shortcode, gallery is not displayed properly. I think some css or js file is not loaded, but browser console log is not showing any error.

Question is: do I need to modify my theme files to get shortcodes working?

My site: https://novy.woodtek.cz

Shortcode is supposed to be displayed in "Reference" section. It is there, but not visible.

Please help me. I will be glad for your ideas.

Thank you

Eduard

Comment: You need to fix the errors already present in custom.js, then it should work

Comment: Fixed, but didn't help. Problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. Problem was that I had not 'wp_head();` in header.php and wp_footer(); in footer.php.

Now it is working.